# No features contain non-null values of "system:time_start". NDBI

Tags: google-earth-engine, chart

I've run into the stated error with this code on Google Earth Engine:

```
var L8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_32DAY_TOA');
var L8_MedianWinter = L8.filterDate('2014-03-01', '2014-07-30').median();
var ndbi = L8_MedianWinter.normalizedDifference(['B6', 'B5']).rename('NDBI');
var ndbiParams = {
  min: -1, 
  max: 1, 
  palette: ['cyan', 'red']
};
Map.addLayer(ndbi.clip(table), ndbiParams, 'ndbi');
var bands = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B10', 'B11', 'NDBI'];
var ndbi16Trends = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection:ndbi,
  regions:table,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  band: 'NDBI',
  scale: 30
}); // chart changes in NDVI 
print(ndbi16Trends);
```

Can anyone point me to why there may be an issue still? I'm not sure how to add in system:time-start.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion()` function, which wants to receive an `ImageCollection` and plot a time series using temporal information in the `ImageCollection`'s metadata. However, you are passing a single `Image`: `ndbi`. One way to diagnose this is to include more `print()` statements in your code.

If you want to make a bar chart comparing max ndbi across your regions, use `ui.Chart.Image.byRegion()` instead, and set the chart type to ColumnChart.

Conversely, if you want to plot variation among your regions across time, you need to take a few steps back and generate an `ImageCollection` of ndbi values from your Landsat data (rather than an `Image` of ndbi created from one reduced median Landsat `Image`).

Please also note that because you didn't include the definition of `table` in your code, I used a stand-in table, counties from Maine. Also, I use a 1000m scale argument in the plots to save computer effort.

```
// A stand-in feature collection; Maine counties
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("TIGER/2018/Counties").filter(ee.Filter.eq("STATEFP","23"));
print("table",table);
Map.addLayer(table, {}, "counties");

// Access the ImageCollection and select time window of interest
var L8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_32DAY_TOA')
  .filterDate('2014-03-01', '2014-07-30');
print("L8",L8);
// Generates a single "median winter" image
var L8_MedianWinter = L8.median();
print("L8_MedianWinter",L8_MedianWinter);
// Generates a single NDBI image based on median winter
var ndbi = L8_MedianWinter.normalizedDifference(['B6', 'B5']).rename('NDBI');
print("ndbi",ndbi);

// A function to calculate NDBI and retain image properties 
var calcNDBI = function(i){
  var L8_roi = i.clip(table);
  var ndbi = L8_roi.normalizedDifference(['B6', 'B5']).rename('NDBI');
  return(ndbi.copyProperties(i, i.propertyNames()));
};
// Map the function to the Landsat ImageCollection
var ndbi_timeseries = L8
  .map(calcNDBI);
print("ndbi_timeseries",ndbi_timeseries);

// Define viz parameters
var ndbiParams = {
  min: -1, 
  max: 1, 
  palette: ['cyan', 'red']
};
Map.addLayer(ndbi.clip(table), ndbiParams, 'ndbi');


// A Bar chart from the reduced ndbi image
var ndbi16Regions = ui.Chart.image.byRegion({
  image:ndbi,
  regions:table,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  scale: 1000
}).setChartType('ColumnChart'); // chart comparison across regions 
print(ndbi16Regions);

// A line chart with ndbi time series by region
var ndbi16Trends = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection: ndbi_timeseries,
  regions: table,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  band: "NDBI",
  scale: 1000,
}); // chart comparison across time 
print(ndbi16Trends);
```

Bar chart (`ui.Chart.image.byRegion()`):

[image: Bar chart - comparing regions]

Line chart (`ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion()`):
[image: Line chart - time series]